# Numpy ndarray in cython, runs slow. what did i do wrong?

Tags: numpy, cython

The profile shows it took 1.857 seconds to run vs running in pure python which takes ~5 seconds. quite far from the speed improvement i am expecting.

3 function calls in 1.857 seconds
Ordered by: internal time

ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
1    1.853    1.853    1.853    1.853 {balCalc2.runLoans}
1    0.004    0.004    1.857    1.857 :1()
1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}

Here is the code i am running...

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
DTYPE = np.float64
ctypedef np.float64_t DTYPE_t
cimport cython
@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.nonecheck(False)

cdef double c2p(double upb):return 0.12
cdef double c2d(double upb):return 0.22
cdef double d2c(double upb):return 0.20
cdef double d2l(double upb):return 0.10
cdef double d2m(double upb):return 0.05
cdef double ficoDrift(double fico): return fico
cdef double genSeverity(char* state, double appraisal, double default, double count_dq): return 0.6
cdef double genWac(double CollType, double mod_age, double wac): return wac
cdef double genSchWac(double CollType, double wala, double wac): return wac
cdef double genAmort(double wac, double wam, double wala, double upb, double status):
    if status == 0.0:
        return 1.0
    else:
        return 0.0


cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=1] genNextStat(double random_number, char* pooltype1, char* state, np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=1] arryLoans):
    cdef double CollType = arryLoans[0]
    cdef double period = arryLoans[1]
    cdef double upb = arryLoans[2]
    cdef double defer = arryLoans[3]
    cdef double sch_wac = arryLoans[4]
    cdef double wac = arryLoans[5]
    cdef double wam = arryLoans[6]
    cdef double wala = arryLoans[7]
    cdef double fico = arryLoans[8]
    cdef double appraisal = arryLoans[9]
    cdef double mba_stat = arryLoans[10]
    cdef double mod_stat = arryLoans[11]
    cdef double mod_age = arryLoans[12]
    cdef double count_c = arryLoans[13]
    cdef double count_dq = arryLoans[14]
    cdef double prepay = 0.0
    cdef double default = 0.0
    cdef double amort = 0.0
    cdef double loss = 0.0
    cdef double forgive = 0.0
    cdef double prob_p
    cdef double prop_d
    cdef double prob_c
    cdef double prob_m
    cdef double prob_l
    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=1] value

    period += 1.0
    wala += 1.0
    wam -= 1.0
    sch_wac = genSchWac(CollType, wala, wac)
    wac = genWac(CollType, mod_age, wala)
    amort = genAmort(wac, wam, wala, upb, mba_stat)
    upb -= amort

    prob_c = d2c(upb)
    prob_m = d2m(upb)
    prob_l = d2l(upb)
    prob_p = c2p(upb)
    prob_d = c2d(upb)

    #omit some operation here...

    value = np.array([CollType, period, upb, defer, sch_wac, wac, wam, wala, fico, appraisal, mba_stat, mod_stat, mod_age, count_c, count_dq, amort, prepay, default, loss, forgive])

    return value


def runLoans(np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=1] initLoan = np.array([10.0, 360.0, 10000.0, 50000.0, 6.0, 6.0, 350.0, 9.0, 600.0, 150000.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0])):
    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=2] loans = np.zeros((360000, 20))
    cdef size_t i
    cdef double rn = 0.53
    cdef char* pooltype = 'MBS'
    cdef char* prop_stat = 'CA'
    loans[0] = initLoan

    for i in range(1,360000):
        loans[i] = genNextStat(rn, pooltype, prop_stat, loans[i-1])

    return loans
```

Just curious how should i improve the speed...

Answer (score 2):

Have you run cython -a  ?

This generates a html file where lines are coloured where there are calls to python interpretor.

Having done this on your code, I can immediately see the slow bit seems to be in how you build the numpy array to return in your function genNextStat.

I suggest you find a better way to do this. You'll know it's fixed when you get rid of the yellow!

Note the easiest way to do this would be to pass *loans* to the genNextStat method and the current row so that it just populates the row of the array which is created outside the loop.

Comment: modified the code and put the loop inside genNextStat as you mentioned, it worked!!! thanks!

Answer (score 2):

the following line will create a list and call python function:

```
value = np.array([CollType, period, upb, defer, sch_wac, wac, wam, wala, fico, appraisal, 
  mba_stat, mod_stat, mod_age, count_c, count_dq, amort, prepay, default, loss, forgive])
```

you can pass `loans` array and the index to `genNextStat()`, and let it fill the array directly. Something like this:

```
cdef genNextStat(double random_number, char* pooltype1, char* state, np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=2] loans, int idx):
    cdef double CollType = loans[idx, 0]
    cdef double period = loans[idx, 1]
    cdef double upb = loans[idx, 2]
    cdef double defer = loans[idx, 3]
    cdef double sch_wac = loans[idx, 4]
    cdef double wac = loans[idx, 5]
    cdef double wam = loans[idx, 6]
    cdef double wala = loans[idx, 7]
    cdef double fico = loans[idx, 8]
    cdef double appraisal = loans[idx, 9]
    cdef double mba_stat = loans[idx, 10]
    cdef double mod_stat = loans[idx, 11]
    cdef double mod_age = loans[idx, 12]
    cdef double count_c = loans[idx, 13]
    cdef double count_dq = loans[idx, 14]

    #...

    idx += 1
    loans[idx, 0] = CollType
    loans[idx, 1] = period
    loans[idx, 2] = upb
    loans[idx, 3] = defer
    loans[idx, 4] = sch_wac
    loans[idx, 5] = wac
    loans[idx, 6] = wam
    loans[idx, 7] = wala
    loans[idx, 8] = fico
    loans[idx, 9] = appraisal
    loans[idx, 10] = mba_stat
    loans[idx, 11] = mod_stat
    loans[idx, 12] = mod_age
    loans[idx, 13] = count_c
    loans[idx, 14] = count_dq
    loans[idx, 15] = amort
    loans[idx, 16] = prepay
    loans[idx, 17] = default
    loans[idx, 18] = loss
    loans[idx, 19] = forgive

the code in `runLoans`:

    for i in range(1,360000):
        genNextStat(rn, pooltype, prop_stat, loans, i-1)
```